# Erase signatures from the Mac OS Catalina V10.15 Preview app forever

Tags: catalina, security, preview, digital-signature

I've been using the [Preview App](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/preview/welcome/mac) to generate my passwords and to be able to sign virtually. But now what I want to do **is to erase them completely, so that nobody can access them.**

For example, if I sell my Mac in a hurry, or if someone accesses my Mac, I want to make it impossible to access those signatures.

I don't mean to press the X (cross) that appears after generating the signature; because I think that by pressing that, that signature must be saved somewhere. I don't know. What I'm saying is to **eliminate it in a more strict way, forever.**

[image: Example sign]

Is it possible to do this? How?

Comment: If you're selling your Mac, why not just wipe the hard drive and be *sure* they're gone?

Comment: Is that what I don't know, wiping the hard drive (which I guess is a factory reset) wipes the whole drive and there's no information left of anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Signatures are stored in a property list file at the following path:

```
~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Preview/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Preview.signatures.plist
```

You can remove this file and empty your trash to be sure they're gone. Any security/assurance you need beyond this will require advanced techniques or a complete wipe of your hard drive.